# Easily configurable command arguments for a single WinForms executable?

Tags: c#, winforms

I've created a very simple Windows Form application that uses .NET 2.0 and runs from a single executable.

These single executables will be deployed to multiple users to prompt and collect information.

The catch is that I want to have the information emailed to a specific email address that can vary based on the user the executable is sent to. But, I do not want to rebuild the executable when the email changes.

I can pass command arguments to the executable via command line of course or a shortcut, but I simply want the user to enter information into the form and click submit and have it sent to a predefined email address that can vary based on the user the executable is sent to.

I can bundle the executable with a batch file that runs the executable with the command argument or a config file. But, I want to keep the deployment simple, one file if possible.

Is it possible to do this with an MSI? Am I totally missing something obvious here?

I want the person who is sending the executable out to the user to be able to easily change the email address that the WinForm will send the data to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your users are going to be changing the email address you might want to think about a simpler delivery mechanism than a config file, which is fragile in the sense that if a user deletes a `>` accidentally your app will throw `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException`.

One simpler solution than the app config file would be a text file with just the target email address in it, included in the same directory as the app.  Your users would have an easier time editing it - or just dropping a new file in.  Of course this relies on them having rights to that directory.

Another option is to treat it like a normal setting.  Prompt the end user for the actual email on first run, and store it using a user specific setting, i.e. `Properties.Settings.Default.SettingName`.  Then, give your users a UI function to change it on demand.

Comment: I thought the application settings would work perfectly. Unfortunately the executable is deployed as follows. Triage person sets up email address for executable > Executable is then sent to the user > User runs executable. The user persisted setting works, but when the executable is sent to the end user, the setting is lost. Application scoped settings do not write to the config file when changed. I think the text file (editable through the executable) may be the best solution.

Comment: User settings get written to the local user account's protected storage, and are definitely per user/machine rather than stored with the app.  I really meant that the end user enters the target email, but that doesn't sound feasible.

Comment: Right, that was our first thought (having the user enter the email), but we want to make it as simple as possible. :P I've got the go ahead to use a simple data file that will store the information entered by the Triage person. I'll mark this one as the answer.

Comment: Great, thanks.  There's lots of more scalable solutions, but keeping it simple is often the best approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could use an app.config file.

Right click the project and select Add->New Item->Application Configuration File

Have something like:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UserEmail" value="test@test.com" />
  </appSettings>
</coniguration>
```

And in your code retrieve the config value like:

```
string email = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserEmail"];
```

Then you just need to change the value in the config file before sending it to the user, and they can also update it on their own.

Comment: Like I said in the original question, I want to keep it to a single file if possible.

Comment: @lionpants Not many applications consist of only 1 single file. Another much more complicated option would be to create an InstallShield installer and have it write the email value into the registry and then retrieve the value from the registry in your code.

Comment: @mclaassen But even then, you're going to rebuild _something_ when the address needs to change.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Why would you need to rebuild anything to change the app.config value?

Comment: I was referring to the registry idea.  Whatever writes that value, app or install, would have to be rebuilt whenever that address is to change.

Answer (score 0):

One slightly different solution would be to have every instance send email to the *same* email address, with the 'from' being an address based on the user's Windows logged in account and domain.

Then, create a receiving email account that those emails arrive at with a filter to redirect the mail to the appropriate destination.  You didn't say what email system you were using, but Exchange allows this quite simply, for example (as do other systems like GMail).

A more labor-intensive variant on this centralized design would be to create a small web service that your exe queries, with the web service telling the exe where it should send mail to.  Again, you'd need a mapping table between Windows user and 'To' addresses.

Comment: Good ideas. Unfortunately, I wouldn't know any mapping information before hand and would not be able to guarantee the domain/username that the information is sent from.

I may have to just settle with the config file.

Comment: The config file is really the sane way to do it, but it does mean the extra file.  One more note on my solution: As long as you have one domain you control, you can use that as the originating domain (i.e. WindowsAccount@yourDomain.com). You also don't need to know the mapping info beforehand; as emails start to come in, you can add each one to the filter.

Comment: Lol. Yes lets create a web service to handle the logic rather than just add a configuration file (although this might be better for an enterprise solution)

Comment: @mclaassen - I was definitely thinking enterprise, although I've seen some pretty crazy solutions at the micro level too!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but here's my try:

You should check out the properties in visual studio:

`Project` -> `yourProjectName Properties...` -> `Settings`

There you can create variables, which can be either application or user scoped. By using user scoped variable, lets say `userEmail`, the program lets you save this information according to the logged in user. This way you can save like 20 different emails in this very same executable, depending on the logged in user.

Save the emails according to user:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.userEmail = "myemail@host.com";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And read them the same way:

```
string email = Properties.Settings.Default.userEmail;
```

Comment: I got excited when Geoff also mentioned this solution below. Unfortunately, the executable will be sent to different computers. When that happens the User persisted settings are lost. Scoping the settings as Application does not write them them to the config file unfortunately.